# How do you switch() on an enum that has multiple similar values in C/C++?

Tags: c, enums

Let's say that I have an enum as such:

```
typedef enum
{
    gray = 4, //Gr[ae]y should be the same
    grey = 4,
    blue = 5,
    red  = 6
} FOO;
```

I then want to switch on this:

```
switch(f){
    case gray:
    case grey:
        printf("The color of an elephant\n"); break;
    case blue:
        printf("The color of the sky\n"); break;
    case red:
        printf("The color of an apple\n"); break;
    default:
        printf("I don't know this color\n"); 
 }
```

Basically I have enum that has values that are essentially synonyms that I want to handle exactly the same way.  I tried the above switch, but it doesn't compile for me. Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck using if/else logic? (I'd rather not as there are 20+ enums and the switch is much cleaner looking

EDIT: Yes, I know that I can just pick one or the other (and no locales are not the solution), but doesn't it seem kind of odd that enums explicitly allow you to declare duplicate values yet you then can't use them in a switch statement? I want to use enums so that I can statically enforce in a library API that they are sending proper values (yes I know you can get around with typecasting, I'm just trying to prevent stupid mistakes and such). If I do so it now seems like I lose the ability to use it in a switch statement.

The compiler is just reducing the logic down to if/else logic.  If 
    case 4:
    case 5:
        bar(); break;

is legal, why can't 
    case 4:
    case 4:
        bar(); break;

be legal?  The compiler should be able to optimize that to one statement and move on.

Comment: Why duplicate the definition of `gray`? Just use one, it means the same thing. If you really need to use both, for whatever reason, you could just do `#define grey gray`.

Comment: *"but it doesn't compile for me"*. What errors does it give?

Comment: Make one of the redundant case statements a comment ;-)

Comment: "Error: Duplicate case value".  (because they're both 4)

Comment: This is just a simple example.  I have values that mean the same thing but are called different things to different people.  For example, in the US, we call it the trunk, but in the UK they call it the boot.  I want to have enums that are logical to both users, but I can have code that simply says "case boot, trunk: printf("Goes in the storage of the automobile\n"); break;"

Comment: @FuriousGeorge - Who's going to be reading your code? Just change the user interface to reflect the locale.

Comment: It's a library that will be used externally.  It's not so much locale's that are the problem here.  I can do this with an if/else block, just hoping there was a cleaner way to do it

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding about the nature of the enum constants you are defining.  If you define two enum constants to have the same value, as you do with `grey` and `gray`, then there is no effective distinction between them.  It is worse than meaningless to use both as case labels in the same switch statement; it's exactly like giving two different cases with label `4`.

Comment: You don't need an if/else block. You just need to pick _one_ of the synonyms as the `case` label. (You can list the other synonyms too as long as they're only in a comment, as suggested earlier.)

Comment: Seriously this is what comments are for. The compiler will see what it needs to see and humans will see what they need to see. Problem solved.

Comment: Seems kind of silly to restrict myself to just one one or the other when enums explictly allow you to declare duplicate values.  I want to use enums so that I can statically enforce that they are sending proper values, yet I now see to lose the ability to use it in a switch statement if I do such.

Comment: You can use multiple names for the same value in the `enum`, but in the `switch` you can use only one for a `case` label. It doesn't matter either, since they evaluate to the same value anyway. I.e. `case grey` will cover both `grey` and `gray`.

Comment: Why do you need both cases inside switch? case gray and case grey both are actually just case 4.

Comment: Who said you needed to "restrict" yourself? Put it this way, you can use any finger you want to depress the `H` key on your computer keyboard. Does that mean you should be able to depress the `H` key with all ten fingers at once? No, use few enough fingers that you can press `H` without also pressing adjacent keys. One finger is best, your choice which one. Basically what you're trying to do is equivalent to fat-fingering the `switch` statement.

Comment: You might want to consider what happens after your US programmers write half the code using the `trunk` enum value and your British programmers write the other half using `boot`. Now you have to train _both_ sets of programmers to recognize an unfamiliar term for that part of a car, moreover they have to know that it might be called by different terms in different parts of the code. Is that better than just picking one word and training half your programmers to recognize it?

Comment: A very simple examply why you can't have 2 `case`s with the same label: `switch(f){ case 4: printf("First case"); break; case 4: printf("Second case"); break; }` what should the compiler do if `f` is `4`?

Comment: @Kninnug I would expect it to complain, though I don't see why grouping them together shouldn't be legit, as the compiler can easily fold them into one statement.

Comment: That would require the compiler to detect grouped `case`s in case two or more have the same label. Even though that is possible, it would be far too much to demand as a minimum requirement. Remember that the Standard dictates the minimum a compiler has to comply to. Requiring such fairly advanced behaviour falls way beyond the scope, especially since it's almost never used.

Comment: Understandable.  So why would I ever want to have enums that have the same value?

Comment: Enum same value example:  `HotColdMask = 0x10, Hot = 0x10, Cold = 0x00, ... FaucetSettings =  (FaucetSettings & ~HotColdMask) |  Hot;`

Comment: One thing I could think of is if you rename some members of your `enum`, but want to keep the old names as well for compatibility. E.g: `enum foo{ bar = 2 /* for compatibility */, foo_bar = 2 };`

Comment: 0_o?? So how would that be different than what I'm asking?  If wanted to rename foo to foo_bar, my switch logic would then need to handle both foo and foo_bar, which is apparently illegal. Yes, I could *just* handle the foo_bar in the switch, but it'd be WAY more clear what my intent was if I could do the double case

Comment: No, the point is that any existing code that still uses the old `bar` identifier won't break. You don't need to handle any other cases, since they have the same value. I would personally just use the new name as the `case` label and maybe mention the old one in a comment.

Comment: You'd update the code to use the new name `foo_bar`, and if/when you removed the old name `bar` at some point, `foo_bar` would still work as it should. Applying the example to this discussion, if `grey` is specified, both UK and US native English speakers should understand what is meant, and non-native English speakers would be able to figure it out if they're used to `gray` instead. Moreover, whichever name you chose for the `case`, both names would be handled the same. If you need distinct handling for each, use different values.

Comment: For this example, using `typedef enum { gray = 4, grey = gray, blue = 5, ...` is the better typedef and using only `gray` in `switch(f){ case gray: ...` is better code.  BTW, I like the question.

Comment: Ahhh.  I really like that idea @chux.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

The C standard requires all the constant expression in the `case` labels for a given `switch` statement to have distinct values. This is checked at compile time. Having two `case` labels with the same value is a *constraint violation*, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. (This could be a non-fatal warning, but I don't know of any compiler that doesn't treat it as a fatal error.)

The rule is stated in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.8.4.2p3:

> The expression of each **`case`** label shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the **`case`** constant expressions in the same
>   **`switch`** statement shall have the same value after conversion.

C++ has similar rules.

This means, for example that this:

```
switch (blah) {
    case 2+2:
    case 4:
        /* ... */
}
```

is also illegal. The compiler checks the *values* of the expressions, regardless of whether they have some distinct meaning to a human reader.

You'll just have to pick either `gray` or `grey`.

(In principle, the standard *could* have permitted two case labels to have the same value as long as they're grouped together, as in your example. But it wasn't defined that way, probably because it wasn't considered useful enough.)

Comment: So let me slightly modify the question and ask "Why does the standard allow you to have duplicate values in enums?" when it seems like the most common use of an enum would be in some sort of switching scenario.

Comment: @FuriousGeorge: That's a different question. Feel free to post it (though it might be closed as "primarily opinion-based"). I think the answer is basically that that's not the *only* thing enums are used for.